# Swift 2.0 - Rearranging a JSON object by sub array

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, swift2, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to create a data dictionary in JSON.
Now I want to arrange one of the sub dictionaries called `fb_friends` by `friend_health_points`.

I tried using Sort or any other manipulation but I get String/JSON errors.

So basically I'm trying to sort it so that 150 health points will be first and 20 will be last in that data dictionary.

This is the data:

```
var data: JSON = [
        "user_id": 7742,
        "name": "Bla",
        "fb_friends": [
            [
                "friend_id": 202072,
                "friend_name": "Bla Bla",
                "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
                "friend_health_points": 50,
            ],
            [
                "friend_id": 502333,
                "friend_name": "hdfghdfghfdgh",
                "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
                "friend_health_points": 150,
            ],
            [
                "friend_id": 202072,
                "friend_name": "gjhkghjk",
                "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
                "friend_health_points": 20,
            ]
]
```

Comment: Your json is invalid

Comment: The json works fine...

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without third-party libraries

```
var data = [
  "user_id": 7742,
  "name": "Bla",
  "fb_friends": [
    [
      "friend_id": 202072,
      "friend_name": "Bla Bla",
      "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
      "friend_health_points": 50,
    ],
    [
      "friend_id": 502333,
      "friend_name": "hdfghdfghfdgh",
      "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
      "friend_health_points": 150,
    ],
    [
      "friend_id": 202072,
      "friend_name": "gjhkghjk",
      "friend_photo_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/",
      "friend_health_points": 20,
    ]
  ]
]

let friends = (data["fb_friends"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]).sort{ ($0["friend_health_points"] as! Int) > $1["friend_health_points"] as! Int}
data["fb_friends"] = friends
print(data)

let json = JSON(data)
```

Comment: Thanks vadian, but I need it as JSON type, I'm building the app to work with a 3rd party API.

Comment: You can easily create a JSON object from the arranged dictionary with `let json = JSON(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer, because the object is of type `SwiftyJSON` I can use `arrayValue` to extract it to array. 
So this will give me back a sorted array of friends.

```
let fbFriends = data["fb_friends"]
let friendsArray = fbFriends.arrayValue
let sortedFriends = friendsArray.sort { $0["friend_health_points"].doubleValue > $1["friend_health_points"].doubleValue }
```